# Search a list and split

Tags: python

First of all sorry for the very basic question but I haven't been able to find an example with the end results I need. In the following example I have a list with numbers and sometimes the numbers are joined like index 2 and 5 in the following list.

```
list = ['1', '2', '3, 4', '5', '6', '7, 8', '9', '10']
```

I would like to search the list and split when it finds a comma so the end result is the following:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, David. Please show what have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck. Showing some initial effort makes the questions to be generally better received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> [x for y in ['1', '2', '3, 4', '5', '6', '7, 8', '9', '10'] for x in y.split(', ')]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is:

```
>>> my_list = ['1', '2', '3, 4', '5', '6', '7, 8', '9', '10']
>>> sum((item.split(', ') for item in my_list), [])
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

or

```
>>> ', '.join(my_list).split(', ')
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```